# Crawl and index specific html tags with NUTCH and Solr

Tags: html, solr, nutch

Right now im crawling a website like ebay for cars, www.standvirtual.com

in my nutch regex-urlfilter.txt +^http://([a-z0-9]*.)*standvirtual.com/carros/anuncios/ like this just crawls the ads of cars, but like this nutch will index the whole content of the page, and i just wanted to index specific parts of that page, like title of the add, description, etc...

example:
lets imagine a scenário that title is a Audi a3 2.0cc
and Audi a3 2000cc with ac, diesel...

Comment: try http://scrapy.org/

Comment: Have you tried [nutch-element-selector](https://github.com/kaqqao/nutch-element-selector)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the parsefilter and use Jsoup selector to select the portion you want to crawl and index.
Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38854219/5676586