# How to select data from specific tags in nutch

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, nutch

I am a newbie in Apache Nutch and I would like to know whether it's possible to crawl selected area of a web page. For instance, select a particular `div` and crawl contents in that `div` only. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Technically, a crawler will always load the full page. What you do with the contents is up to you.

Comment: If it so how can I select contents under a specific tag for next round of crawl ?

Comment: What do you mean by crawling a particular div? You only want to extract URLs that are inside this div? or index only the content of the div?

Comment: I want to extract all the links inside particular div and crawl them and then index.

Comment: @JorgeLuis : Anything on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write a [plugin](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/AboutPlugins) that will extend [HtmlParseFilter](http://nutch.apache.org/apidocs/apidocs-1.8/org/apache/nutch/parse/HtmlParseFilter.html) to achieve your goal.

I reckon you will be doing some of the stuff yourself like parsing the html's specific section, extracting the URLs that you want and add them as outlinks.

**HtmlParseFilter implementation:** (Code below gives the general idea)

```
ParseResult filter(Content content, ParseResult parseResult, HTMLMetaTags metaTags, DocumentFragment doc){
    // get html content
    String htmlContent = new String(content.getContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    // parse html using jsoup or any other library.
    String url = content.getUrl();
    Parse parse = parseResult.get(url);
    ParseData parseData = parse.getData();
    Outlink[] links = parseData.getOutlinks();
    // modify/select only required outlinks
    // return ParsePesult with modified outlinks
    return parseResult;
}
```

Hope this will be helpful.

If you are new to plugin, I have written a simple plugin "[nutch-fetch-page](https://github.com/mshoaib91/nutch-fetch-page)" which saves html pages and text content on a local drive using `HtmlParseFilter` interface. You can fork/download and modify the code.

Comment: Can you add how to set selected outlinks using jsoup ?